# windows7のpowershellのchcp 65001でutf-8に変更する事が出来ない。

Tags: windows, powershell

`chcp 65001` でコードベージを変更しようとすると異常終了する。

コードベージを65001のutf-8に変更する方法をお知えて下さい。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

とりあえず手元のWindows 10では`chcp 65001`の実行に成功しました。
もし異常終了するのであれば、エラーメッセージやイベントログなどを提示してください。第三者には何が起こっているのか全く分かりません。

なお、質問したまま放置されている[windows7のmingw shellで文字化けする](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/32920/4236)の問題とは状況が異なります。そもそも`chcp`はコンソール（コマンドプロンプトやPowerShellで使われるあの黒い枠、UNIXでの端末エミュレーターに相当）のコードページを変更するツールです。つまりコンソール内部で動かすプログラムのコードページとコンソールのコードページとを一致させることが目的です。ところがPoerShellでは内部の文字コードがUnicode（UTF-16）と定まっているため、コードページの変更にあまり意味を成しません。
ですので今回の文字化けは不適切な読み込み処理に由来する可能性もあります。何がどう文字化けしたのか再現手順も提示すべきです。